# Angular-js not updating

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a newbie working on building a web app in Ionic. Here's the code I am stuck at: http://pastebin.com/index/HihYnSk5. Basically, I have a button which when clicked on should display "test" on the All Favors page. From what I can see, test is getting added to favors object in my .js file but it's not getting displayed on the screen. Can someone help out?

Comment: is iterator defined?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should not add `ng-controller="allFavorsCtrl"` in two different elements, they will not share the same `scope` and so updating one will not reflect on the other.

Try to put both elements under a common `<div ng-controller="allFavorsCtrl">`. If you cannot have them both under the same element, then you need to create a `service` to share information across them.

Also, `<span ng-model = "favor">` will not do anything: a `<span>` cannot have a `ng-model`.